# how to make inline div blocks arrange one below another instead of just shrinking in width when looked in mobile device

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a template which is fully responsive but I had to add 3 blocks of 'div' which display inline. They all resize fine except when looked in to a mobile device they really shrink in width because of that their height increases and all 3 'div' become long vertical bars.

I am looking for some suggestions where instead I can make those block go below each another (like a 3 floor building) when looked in a mobile device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be after something like this:

```css
.container{
  margin: 0 2% 5px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width:32%;
  background-color: #cdcdff;
}

.container:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
  .container{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text</div><div class="container">This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text</div><div class="container">This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text and This is long text</div>
</div>
```

**See it in action**

To see this in action, just hit the **Full page** link and resize the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "clear: both" property to your div class can help you I guess. You can also make them display block... Try it and see if you get what you need! Take a look at this site to understand how to define some css only for specific screen sizes: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand but I think you could use a media query to set divs' display property to block, that way they will occupy 100% of their parent's width. Unless you're using fixed widths and floating boxes, in that case just set: `width: 100%`